# handle click event for image inside scrollview

Tags: android

I have a set of images inside horizontal scrollview. I want to perform click event on these images. I have added onClickListener to the images. But its not working. I think since images are inside scrollview the problem arises. Can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used OnTouchListner instead of OnClickListener and applied it to the images inside ScrollView. Now I am able to do it.

@Desiderio : I used ScrollView for some other purpose. I required it for my appn. It doesnt interfere with my pbm. Sorry, I made mistake while explaining my pbm.

Comment: How were you differentiating a scroll event from click event ? I am trying the same but now it triggers every time i touch the area.